# Unix Complex Directory Issue

Tags: bash, unix, grep, cat

I have a master folder named `Server` which has `15(1...f)` `worker` folders and inside each `worker(1...f)` folders there are `slave(1...f)` sub-folders. Inside each `slave` sub-folders there are around approx.2000 files.

Illustrated View :

/Server

```
/1  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/2  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/3  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/4  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/5  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/6  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/7  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/8  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/9  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/a  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/b  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/c  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/d  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/e  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
/f  ----> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
```

I need to `grep` a particular string called "router" inside the files in all the folders in all at once and write it to a file / `cat` all the files inside the folders and write it to one file.

I tried cat,

```
#cat **/* > new_file.txt
```

I got `bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long` as response

I tried grep,

```
#grep -e "router" **/* > new_file.txt
```

Again, I got `bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long` as response.

I know this is complex directory issue . This cannot be changed as the data is obtained from a online resource. Can some one help on how to get the particular line with string `"router"` of the the slave folders and redirect it to a new file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `find` instead of `grep`

```
find . -name "*" -type f -exec grep "router" {} \; > new_file.txt
```

it will find for every files(`"*"`) in  (`.`) directory then `grep "router"` for each of them.

Regards

Claudio

Comment: use `>>` instead of `>` to avoid overwriting

Comment: @ritesht93 f you would insert the command inside a loop like `for` or `while` yes, otherwise you don't need to use `>>`

Comment: Thank you @Claudio. Nice to do it using 'find'. Cool anyway !